# Quit from Unity to native iOS app

Tags: unity, ios

I'm working on iOS application which is going to include a few unity games. 
And I investigate an opportunity to exit from the Unity game to the native iOS app with games list. 
I know that the Unity provides methods `Application.Quit()` and `Application.Unload()`

I haven't try but I'm not sure that `Application.Unload()` is correct ways to exit from unity to the native iOS app.

Comment: Googling "unity embed game into native app" leads to a few articles which might help you. I believe neither "quit" nor "unload" will help you switch active contexts.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use Application.Quit() on iOS devices per unity documentation. If this is an embedded application inside an iOS application then Application.Unload() is exactly what you want. It will release the memory associated with Unity scenes and game elements.

If this isn't an embedded game you should let the user decide when to close the game application.

Comment: I tried that and I was thinking that Application.Unload() close Unity player and just display iOS native app, but nothing happened.

Comment: @Atlantis that seems like something you should cover in your question.